# How to enable support for Russian language in TikzEdt?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I use a distribution for MikTeX for Windows and TikzEdt (http://www.tikzedt.org/).

How to enable support for Russian language in TikzEdt?

This code does not work:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node (h) at (1,1) {Привет};
  \node (w) at (3,3) {мир};
  \draw (h) edge (w);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I tried to change the configuration, but it did not help.

```
%\documentclass{article}
\documentclass{extarticle}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage{pscyr}
\usepackage[cp1251]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}
%
\usepackage{tikz,amsmath, amssymb,bm,color}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
% needed for BB
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}
```

How to enable support for Russian letters in TikzEdt 0.2?

[image]

Comment: If I remove `pscyr`, that I don't have, I see no problem.

Comment: \documentclass{extarticle}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel} Does not work!